# Cutting strings at a specific character (starting from the end) in R

Tags: r, substring

I want to cut off the last dot of the names. So the data frame looks like this:

```
> df
  n        names
1 2 Musterman P.
2 3       Max A.
3 5   Chela J.I.
```

And the desired outcome would look like this:

```
> df
  n        names
1 2 Musterman P
2 3       Max A
3 5   Chela J.I
```

I tried multiple wayse using strsplit, but it does not work :(

Comment: `sub("\\.$", "", df$names)` should do it.

Comment: Just to notice, the dot is not always the last character. So some names look like this: Musterman P. A  --> So the desired outcome would look like this: Musterman P

Comment: @user3108348 then why it fails to remove `.I` in your ex.

Answer (score 1):

To delete the part next to last dot.

```
sub("\\.[^.]*$", "", df$names)
```

to delete only the last dot char.

```
sub("\\.([^.]*)$", "\\1", df$names)
```

Comment: Thanks, sub("\\.[^.]*$", "", df$names) works perfect :)